# Visual Studio #pragma once

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pragma, preprocessor-directive

I use the IDE Visual Studio 2013.

Visual Studio has a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive:

```
#pragma once
```

This replaces `#include` guards and removes any possibility of name confliction with less code. My question is that is there any disadvantage to using this, for example decreased portability?

Comment: `Visual Studio has a non-standard ... decreased portability?` What was the question again? Of course non-standard features are less portable than standard ones, even if the difference probably is negligible in this case.

Comment: Yea that's starting to become apparent to me

Answer (score 0):

It is less portable. It works. But then again you are working in the windows environment for why not!